# MPAndroidChart Entry cannot be cast to BarEntry

Tags: java, android, casting, mpandroidchart

I want to create a BarChart using MPAndroidChart but I get the following error `java.lang.ClassCastException: com.github.mikephil.charting.data.Entry cannot be cast to com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarEntry`

I first get the data from a different activity and use that.

First activity:

```
ArrayList<BarEntry> temperature = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < temp.length(); i++) {
    float temp_data = Float.parseFloat(temp.getJSONObject(i).getString("value"));
    float humid_data = Float.parseFloat(humid.getJSONObject(i).getString("value"));
    float time_data = Float.parseFloat(time.getJSONObject(i).getString("time"));

    temperature.add(new BarEntry(time_data, temp_data));
                                humidity.add(new BarEntry(time_data, humid_data));
    }
Intent intent = new Intent(itemView.getContext(), DeviceDataReport.class);
intent.putExtra("temperatureData", temperature);
//put other extras

context.startActivity(intent);
```

In DeviceDataReport:

```
ArrayList<BarEntry> temperature = new ArrayList<>();
if (extras != null) {
        temperature = extras.getParcelableArrayList("temperatureData");
        //get other data
    }


temperatureChart = (BarChart) findViewById(R.id.chart_temp);
BarDataSet set1;
    if (temperatureChart.getData() != null &&
            temperatureChart.getData().getDataSetCount() > 0) {
        set1 = (BarDataSet) temperatureChart.getData().getDataSetByIndex(0);
        set1.setValues(temperature);
        temperatureChart.getData().notifyDataChanged();
        temperatureChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } else {
        set1 = new BarDataSet(temperature, "The year 2017"); //this is where error occurs

        ArrayList<IBarDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<IBarDataSet>();
        dataSets.add(set1);

        BarData data = new BarData(dataSets);

        temperatureChart.setData(data);
    }
```

I don't see any place where I am only using `Entry` instead of `BarEntry`. My xml also says BarChart not LineChart.

Comment: Thanks for the accept @Tirth !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using MPAndroidChart 3.0.1**

I'm sorry to say this looks like an incomplete implementation of `BarEntry`. If you inspect the source, you can see the following:

1. `BarEntry` extends `Entry`
2. `Entry` implements `Parcelable`
3. `BarEntry` doesn't have its own `Parcelable<Creator>`

So when you serialise into a parcel, and then deserialise, you'll get a `List<Entry>` instead of `List<BarEntry>` :-)

For now there is nothing you can do apart from work around this.

You can take the opportunity to refactor to achieve a better separation of layers. `BarEntry` is a member of the view layer or the view model layer. Instead of passing around `BarEntry`, you should probably have a clear model layer which is a mere data object. You can pass lists or arrays of this model layer around in an Intent easily and the consumers can convert to `BarEntry` as necessary.

Alternatively, create an abstraction of a data source. Something like a `TemperatureRepository` class. Then Activitys and Fragments that consume this data can get the data from the repository rather than from an Intent.